# Why doesnt this plugin decode $final?

Tags: php, python, decoding

this is the plugin I am using:

```
add_shortcode( '3', 'execute_python_with_argv3' );

function execute_python_with_argv3() {
    $description = array (     
        array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
        array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
    );

    $application_system = "python ";
    $application_path .= plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    $application_name .= "3.py";
    $separator = " ";
    $application =     $application_system.$application_path.$application_name.$separator;
    $pipes = array();
    $proc = proc_open ($application, $description, $pipes);

    if (is_resource ( $proc )) {
        $response = stream_get_contents ($pipes [1] ); //Reading stdout buffer
    }

    $final = substr(str_replace("'", "", $response), 1);

    echo $final;
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8', $final);
}
```

`$response` is equal to `b'\xc4\x8d\xc4\x99\xc4\x97\xc4\x8d\xc4\x8d\xc4\xaf\xc4\x85'` and `$final` is eaqual to `\xc4\x8d\xc4\x99\xc4\x97\xc4\x8d\xc4\x8d\xc4\xaf\xc4\x85` and with all of this `echo iconv('UTF-8','UTF-8',$final);` should decode and print `čęėččįą`. But it doesn't decode and only print `$final`'s string, but if I paste the string `$final` prints to `iconv`'s string place, it decodes perfectly. Why is this happening? How do I fix this? Thanks.

This is Python script I am using:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
line="čęėččįą";
enc=line.encode('utf-8')
print (enc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment default encoding to `utf-8`.
One way to do it is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

line = "čęėččįą"
enc = line.encode('utf-8')
print (enc)
```